# Plus, Minus, automatic cart update on Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, ajax, magento2.3.3, mini-cart, ajaxaddtocart

I have normal magento 2.3.3 which has the default mini cart as shown below.

[image: The basic mini cart]

And in the above pic by default the quantity as to be manually entered and updated the cart on click.

But I want a mini cart that should have a plus and minus symbol, with synchronous cart update i.e without clicking update cart.

The example has been shown below.

[image: Nedd to bring a mini cart like this]

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: Did you got solution for this?

Comment: No ,I didn't get the answer yet. @Ranganathan

Comment: ok, I will post my answer.

Comment: You can use this extension https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-qty and modify to hide the Update button and trigger the update button on qty increase or decrease.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override `default.html` from

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html

to

> app\design\yourvendor\yourtheme\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart\item\default.html

add + and - button as span tag in line number 74 and 84.

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: product_name"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>

            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->

                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                           for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                    <span class="minus">-</span>
                    <input data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           'data-item-qty': qty,
                           'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                           }, value: qty"
                           type="number"
                           size="4"
                           class="item-qty cart-item-qty">
                    <span class="plus">+</span>
                    <button data-bind="attr: {
                           id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                           'data-cart-item': item_id,
                           title: $t('Update')
                           }"
                            class="update-cart-item"
                            style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

override `sidebar.js` from

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\sidebar.js

to

> app\design\yourvendor\yourtheme\Magento_Checkout\web\js\sidebar.js

marked my custom codes in comments. Please take a look

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'underscore',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/decorate',
    'mage/collapsible',
    'mage/cookies'
], function ($, authenticationPopup, customerData, alert, confirm, _) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('mage.sidebar', {
        options: {
            isRecursive: true,
            minicart: {
                maxItemsVisible: 3
            }
        },
        scrollHeight: 0,
        shoppingCartUrl: window.checkout.shoppingCartUrl,

        /**
         * Create sidebar.
         * @private
         */
        _create: function () {
            this._initContent();
        },

        /**
         * Update sidebar block.
         */
        update: function () {
            $(this.options.targetElement).trigger('contentUpdated');
            this._calcHeight();
            this._isOverflowed();
        },

        /**
         * @private
         */
        _initContent: function () {
            var self = this,
                events = {};

            this.element.decorate('list', this.options.isRecursive);

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            events['click ' + this.options.button.close] = function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                $(self.options.targetElement).dropdownDialog('close');
            };
            events['click ' + this.options.button.checkout] = $.proxy(function () {
                var cart = customerData.get('cart'),
                    customer = customerData.get('customer'),
                    element = $(this.options.button.checkout);

                if (!customer().firstname && cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed === false) {
                    // set URL for redirect on successful login/registration. It's postprocessed on backend.
                    $.cookie('login_redirect', this.options.url.checkout);

                    if (this.options.url.isRedirectRequired) {
                        element.prop('disabled', true);
                        location.href = this.options.url.loginUrl;
                    } else {
                        authenticationPopup.showModal();
                    }

                    return false;
                }
                element.prop('disabled', true);
                location.href = this.options.url.checkout;
            }, this);

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                confirm({
                    content: self.options.confirmMessage,
                    actions: {
                        /** @inheritdoc */
                        confirm: function () {
                            self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
                        },

                        /** @inheritdoc */
                        always: function (e) {
                            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        }
                    }
                });
            };

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            events['click ' + '.minicart-items-wrapper .plus'] = function (event) {//Custom event
                var qtyVal = parseInt($(event.target).parent().find(this.options.item.qty).val());
                $(this.options.item.qty).val(qtyVal + 1);
                event.stopPropagation();
                self._updateItemQty($(event.target).parent().find(this.options.item.button));
            };

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            events['click ' + '.minicart-items-wrapper .minus'] = function (event) {//Custom event
                var qtyVal = parseInt($(event.target).parent().find(this.options.item.qty).val());
                if(qtyVal > 1){
                    $(this.options.item.qty).val(qtyVal - 1);
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    self._updateItemQty($(event.target).parent().find(this.options.item.button));
                }
            };

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            events['keyup ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {//Hide event for not displaying update button
                //self._showItemButton($(event.target));
            };

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            events['change ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {//Hide event for not displaying update button
                //self._showItemButton($(event.target));
            };

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            events['click ' + this.options.item.button] = function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                self._updateItemQty($(event.currentTarget));
            };

            /**
             * @param {jQuery.Event} event
             */
            events['focusout ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {
                self._validateQty($(event.currentTarget));
            };

            this._on(this.element, events);
            this._calcHeight();
            this._isOverflowed();
        },

        /**
         * Add 'overflowed' class to minicart items wrapper element
         *
         * @private
         */
        _isOverflowed: function () {
            var list = $(this.options.minicart.list),
                cssOverflowClass = 'overflowed';

            if (this.scrollHeight > list.innerHeight()) {
                list.parent().addClass(cssOverflowClass);
            } else {
                list.parent().removeClass(cssOverflowClass);
            }
        },

        /**
         * @param {HTMLElement} elem
         * @private
         */
        _showItemButton: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item'),
                itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');

            if (this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
                $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).show('fade', 300);
            } else if (elem.val() == 0) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            } else {
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            }
        },

        /**
         * @param {*} origin - origin qty. 'data-item-qty' attribute.
         * @param {*} changed - new qty.
         * @returns {Boolean}
         * @private
         */
        _isValidQty: function (origin, changed) {
            return origin != changed && //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                changed.length > 0 &&
                changed - 0 == changed && //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                changed - 0 > 0;
        },

        /**
         * @param {Object} elem
         * @private
         */
        _validateQty: function (elem) {
            var itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');

            if (!this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
                elem.val(itemQty);
            }
        },

        /**
         * @param {HTMLElement} elem
         * @private
         */
        _hideItemButton: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

            $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).hide('fade', 300);
        },

        /**
         * @param {HTMLElement} elem
         * @private
         */
        _updateItemQty: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

            this._ajax(this.options.url.update, {
                'item_id': itemId,
                'item_qty': $('#cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty').val()
            }, elem, this._updateItemQtyAfter);
        },

        /**
         * Update content after update qty
         *
         * @param {HTMLElement} elem
         */
        _updateItemQtyAfter: function (elem) {
            var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

            if (!_.isUndefined(productData)) {
                $(document).trigger('ajax:updateCartItemQty');

                if (window.location.href === this.shoppingCartUrl) {
                    window.location.reload(false);
                }
            }
            this._hideItemButton(elem);
        },

        /**
         * @param {HTMLElement} elem
         * @private
         */
        _removeItem: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

            this._ajax(this.options.url.remove, {
                'item_id': itemId
            }, elem, this._removeItemAfter);
        },

        /**
         * Update content after item remove
         *
         * @param {Object} elem
         * @private
         */
        _removeItemAfter: function (elem) {
            var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

            if (!_.isUndefined(productData)) {
                $(document).trigger('ajax:removeFromCart', {
                    productIds: [productData['product_id']]
                });
            }
        },

        /**
         * Retrieves product data by Id.
         *
         * @param {Number} productId - product Id
         * @returns {Object|undefined}
         * @private
         */
        _getProductById: function (productId) {
            return _.find(customerData.get('cart')().items, function (item) {
                return productId === Number(item['item_id']);
            });
        },

        /**
         * @param {String} url - ajax url
         * @param {Object} data - post data for ajax call
         * @param {Object} elem - element that initiated the event
         * @param {Function} callback - callback method to execute after AJAX success
         */
        _ajax: function (url, data, elem, callback) {
            $.extend(data, {
                'form_key': $.mage.cookies.get('form_key')
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: data,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,

                /** @inheritdoc */
                beforeSend: function () {
                    elem.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                },

                /** @inheritdoc */
                complete: function () {
                    elem.attr('disabled', null);
                }
            })
                .done(function (response) {
                    var msg;

                    if (response.success) {
                        callback.call(this, elem, response);
                    } else {
                        msg = response['error_message'];

                        if (msg) {
                            alert({
                                content: msg
                            });
                        }
                    }
                })
                .fail(function (error) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                });
        },

        /**
         * Calculate height of minicart list
         *
         * @private
         */
        _calcHeight: function () {
            var self = this,
                height = 0,
                counter = this.options.minicart.maxItemsVisible,
                target = $(this.options.minicart.list),
                outerHeight;

            self.scrollHeight = 0;
            target.children().each(function () {

                if ($(this).find('.options').length > 0) {
                    $(this).collapsible();
                }
                outerHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

                if (counter-- > 0) {
                    height += outerHeight;
                }
                self.scrollHeight += outerHeight;
            });

            target.parent().height(height);
        }
    });

    return $.mage.sidebar;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it's working good.

Comment: Is it your soltion work for 2.4.1?

Answer (score 0):

Override default.html from

and paste this code

```
    <div class="product-item-details">
        <strong class="product-item-name">
            <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
            <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: $parent.getProductNameUnsanitizedHtml(product_name)"></a>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                <span data-bind="html: $parent.getProductNameUnsanitizedHtml(product_name)"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </strong>

        <!-- ko if: options.length -->
        <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
            <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

            <div data-role="content" class="content">
                <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                <dl class="product options list">
                    <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                    <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                    <dd class="values">
                        <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: $parents[1].getOptionValueUnsanitizedHtml(option.value.join('<br/>'))"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && ['file', 'html'].includes(option.option_type)) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: $parents[1].getOptionValueUnsanitizedHtml(option.value)"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && !['file', 'html'].includes(option.option_type)) -->
                        <span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dd>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-pricing">
            <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->

            <div class="details-map">
                <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="details-qty qty">
                 <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                       for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label> 
               <span data-bind="attr: {
                       id: item_id
                       }" class="minus" >-</span>
                <input data-bind="attr: {
                       id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                       'data-cart-item': item_id,
                       'data-item-qty': qty,
                       'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                       }, value: qty"
                       type="number"
                       size="4"
                       readonly="" 
                       class="item-qty cart-item-qty qty">
                <span data-bind="attr: {
                       id: item_id
                       }" class="plus">+</span>
                <button data-bind="attr: {
                       id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                       'data-cart-item': item_id,
                       title: $t('Update')
                       }"
                        class="update-cart-item"
                        style="display: none">
                   <!--  <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span> -->
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

=========================

override sidebar.js from
and paste this code

define([
'jquery',
'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
'underscore',
'jquery/ui',
'mage/decorate',
'mage/collapsible',
'mage/cookies'
], function ($, authenticationPopup, customerData, alert, confirm, _) {
'use strict';

```
$.widget('mage.sidebar', {
    options: {
        isRecursive: true,
        minicart: {
            maxItemsVisible: 3
        }
    },
    scrollHeight: 0,
    shoppingCartUrl: window.checkout.shoppingCartUrl,

    /**
     * Create sidebar.
     * @private
     */
    _create: function () {
        this._initContent();
    },

    /**
     * Update sidebar block.
     */
    update: function () {
        $(this.options.targetElement).trigger('contentUpdated');
        this._calcHeight();
        this._isOverflowed();
    },

    /**
     * @private
     */
    _initContent: function () {
        var self = this,
            events = {};

        this.element.decorate('list', this.options.isRecursive);

        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['click ' + this.options.button.close] = function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(self.options.targetElement).dropdownDialog('close');
        };
        events['click ' + this.options.button.checkout] = $.proxy(function () {
            var cart = customerData.get('cart'),
                customer = customerData.get('customer'),
                element = $(this.options.button.checkout);

            if (!customer().firstname && cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed === false) {
                // set URL for redirect on successful login/registration. It's postprocessed on backend.
                $.cookie('login_redirect', this.options.url.checkout);

                if (this.options.url.isRedirectRequired) {
                    element.prop('disabled', true);
                    location.href = this.options.url.loginUrl;
                } else {
                    authenticationPopup.showModal();
                }

                return false;
            }
            element.prop('disabled', true);
            location.href = this.options.url.checkout;
        }, this);

        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            confirm({
                content: self.options.confirmMessage,
                actions: {
                    /** @inheritdoc */
                    confirm: function () {
                        self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
                    },

                    /** @inheritdoc */
                    always: function (e) {
                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    }
                }
            });
        };

        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['click ' + '.minicart-items-wrapper .plus'] = function (event) {//Custom event
            var plusId=event.target.id;
            var qtyBoxId='#cart-item-'+plusId+'-qty';
            var qtyVal = parseInt($(event.target).parent().find(this.options.item.qty).val());
            $(qtyBoxId).val(qtyVal + 1);
            event.stopPropagation();
            self._updateItemQty($(event.target).parent().find(this.options.item.button));
        };

        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['click ' + '.minicart-items-wrapper .minus'] = function (event) {//Custom event
            var minusId=event.target.id;
            var qtyBoxId='#cart-item-'+minusId+'-qty';
            var qtyVal = parseInt($(event.target).parent().find(this.options.item.qty).val());
            if(qtyVal > 1){
                $(qtyBoxId).val(qtyVal - 1);
                event.stopPropagation();
                self._updateItemQty($(event.target).parent().find(this.options.item.button));
            }
        };

        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['keyup ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {//Hide event for not displaying update button
            //self._showItemButton($(event.target));
        };

        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['change ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {//Hide event for not displaying update button
            //self._showItemButton($(event.target));
        };

        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['click ' + this.options.item.button] = function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            self._updateItemQty($(event.currentTarget));
        };

        /**
         * @param {jQuery.Event} event
         */
        events['focusout ' + this.options.item.qty] = function (event) {
            self._validateQty($(event.currentTarget));
        };

        this._on(this.element, events);
        this._calcHeight();
        this._isOverflowed();
    },

    /**
     * Add 'overflowed' class to minicart items wrapper element
     *
     * @private
     */
    _isOverflowed: function () {
        var list = $(this.options.minicart.list),
            cssOverflowClass = 'overflowed';

        if (this.scrollHeight > list.innerHeight()) {
            list.parent().addClass(cssOverflowClass);
        } else {
            list.parent().removeClass(cssOverflowClass);
        }
    },

    /**
     * @param {HTMLElement} elem
     * @private
     */
    _showItemButton: function (elem) {
        var itemId = elem.data('cart-item'),
            itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');

        if (this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
            $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).show('fade', 300);
        } else if (elem.val() == 0) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
            this._hideItemButton(elem);
        } else {
            this._hideItemButton(elem);
        }
    },

    /**
     * @param {*} origin - origin qty. 'data-item-qty' attribute.
     * @param {*} changed - new qty.
     * @returns {Boolean}
     * @private
     */
    _isValidQty: function (origin, changed) {
        return origin != changed && //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
            changed.length > 0 &&
            changed - 0 == changed && //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
            changed - 0 > 0;
    },

    /**
     * @param {Object} elem
     * @private
     */
    _validateQty: function (elem) {
        var itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');

        if (!this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
            elem.val(itemQty);
        }
    },

    /**
     * @param {HTMLElement} elem
     * @private
     */
    _hideItemButton: function (elem) {
        var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

        $('#update-cart-item-' + itemId).hide('fade', 300);
    },

    /**
     * @param {HTMLElement} elem
     * @private
     */
    _updateItemQty: function (elem) {
        var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

        this._ajax(this.options.url.update, {
            'item_id': itemId,
            'item_qty': $('#cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty').val()
        }, elem, this._updateItemQtyAfter);
    },

    /**
     * Update content after update qty
     *
     * @param {HTMLElement} elem
     */
    _updateItemQtyAfter: function (elem) {
        var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

        if (!_.isUndefined(productData)) {
            $(document).trigger('ajax:updateCartItemQty');

            if (window.location.href === this.shoppingCartUrl) {
                window.location.reload(false);
            }
        }
        this._hideItemButton(elem);
    },

    /**
     * @param {HTMLElement} elem
     * @private
     */
    _removeItem: function (elem) {
        var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

        this._ajax(this.options.url.remove, {
            'item_id': itemId
        }, elem, this._removeItemAfter);
    },

    /**
     * Update content after item remove
     *
     * @param {Object} elem
     * @private
     */
    _removeItemAfter: function (elem) {
        var productData = this._getProductById(Number(elem.data('cart-item')));

        if (!_.isUndefined(productData)) {
            $(document).trigger('ajax:removeFromCart', {
                productIds: [productData['product_id']]
            });
        }
    },

    /**
     * Retrieves product data by Id.
     *
     * @param {Number} productId - product Id
     * @returns {Object|undefined}
     * @private
     */
    _getProductById: function (productId) {
        return _.find(customerData.get('cart')().items, function (item) {
            return productId === Number(item['item_id']);
        });
    },

    /**
     * @param {String} url - ajax url
     * @param {Object} data - post data for ajax call
     * @param {Object} elem - element that initiated the event
     * @param {Function} callback - callback method to execute after AJAX success
     */
    _ajax: function (url, data, elem, callback) {
        $.extend(data, {
            'form_key': $.mage.cookies.get('form_key')
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            context: this,

            /** @inheritdoc */
            beforeSend: function () {
                elem.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            },

            /** @inheritdoc */
            complete: function () {
                elem.attr('disabled', null);
            }
        })
            .done(function (response) {
                var msg;

                if (response.success) {
                    callback.call(this, elem, response);
                } else {
                    msg = response['error_message'];

                    if (msg) {
                        alert({
                            content: msg
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
            .fail(function (error) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    },

    /**
     * Calculate height of minicart list
     *
     * @private
     */
    _calcHeight: function () {
        var self = this,
            height = 0,
            counter = this.options.minicart.maxItemsVisible,
            target = $(this.options.minicart.list),
            outerHeight;

        self.scrollHeight = 0;
        target.children().each(function () {

            if ($(this).find('.options').length > 0) {
                $(this).collapsible();
            }
            outerHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

            if (counter-- > 0) {
                height += outerHeight;
            }
            self.scrollHeight += outerHeight;
        });

        target.parent().height(height);
    }
});

return $.mage.sidebar;
```

});

Hope this code work perfect